# How to increase speed of Webclient.UploadFileAsync function?

Tags: c#, web-services, file-upload, .net-4.5, webclient

I am using `Webclient.UploadFileAsync` function to call a rest webservice  to upload files to a server. The uploads to server can also be done from a web application.

The server side processing is in milliseconds. So, most of the time of upload is spent in transport. I am able to upload a 6.28 MB file from web application in 2 minutes, But the same upload if done from my winform application using `Webclient.UploadFileAsync` takes 3 minutes.

Difference between web browser upload & webservice upload is that the former directly saves a file to server and in case of webservice first the webservice is called and then file is saved to the server.

So,what is the reason for such a huge difference in speed ? And how can this difference be reduced ?

Update: I tried using fiddler as suggested, and found an interesting thing.When I uploaded a file, while the fiddler was running, I got huge improvement in upload speed.Close to the speed of web application.And, when I tried uploading when the fiddler wasn't running, I got very slow upload speed as before.So, there seems to be a bug in webclient class.How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Try some network tracing tools such as Fiddler and WireShark to determine what is going on at the network level.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments due to my reputation, so sorry for getting your hopes up in advance, but it would seem that since you have to go through middleware so to speak, the overall load time is increased, if it's not that important and you have the correct tools to do so, there are many FTP clients and libraries out there that could do this, and probably quicker than your web server's speed. Although if it's required for you to go through a web server, I wouldn't have much of an answer other than perhaps using an external webclient that can *maybe* run slightly faster.

So to sort of answer your question, using a secure FTP library would most likely be faster, and the speed difference is mainly due to the middleware you have to go through before hitting your actual server.